# Spring AOP+Custom Annotation+SpEL

Tags: annotations, aop, spring-aop, spring-annotations, spring-el

I am trying to implement SpEL in my custom Annotation in a similar fashion how @Cachable implement

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames="books", key="#isbn.rawNumber")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

Here is my code Sample:

Custom Annotation:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface StoreRequest {
    
    public boolean enable() default true;
    
    public String name() default "" ;

}
```

Aspect:

```
@Before("@annotation(storeRequest)")
public void saveRequest(JoinPoint ijoinPoint, StoreRequest storeRequest) {
    if (storeRequest.enable()) {
        System.out.println("Aspect in enabled for "+ storeRequest.name());
    } else {
            System.out.println("Aspect in disabled for "+ storeRequest.name();
    }

}
```

Service:

```
@Override
    @StoreRequest(name = "#name")
    public void aspectCheck(String name){
    ....
    ...
    ...
}
```

Let's say the param value is BOB for aspectCheck method, This piece of code prints as "Aspect in enabled for #name". where as I expect is as "Aspect in enabled for BOB".

Now, I know that Spel doesn't work magically, and I need to write extra lines of code for my custom annotation to implement SpEL. I would appreciate if any one could help me how to do it.

Comment: How can you use `@StoreRequest(referenceId = "#name")` if your annotation does not even declare a `referenceId` parameter? Maybe you want to fix your sample code first before I can answer your question. I also need to know how much variation or flexibility there is in your SpEL expression. Is it always `#name` and is it always a string or can there be other expression names, types, maybe multiple expressions? The solution can be very simple or quite complex, depending on your concrete problem. I do not want to suggest an overly simplistic approach which then maybe is insufficient for you.

Comment: Another question is why you need SpEL at all if the annotation is only used in the aspect. You could get the method parameter `name` directly from the aspect and generate the string inside the aspect. I am asking before I might suggest a solution involving SpEL, because I want to avoid this being an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898) where you have a technical solution in mind instead of just explaining the actual problem, for which there might be a simpler solution. SpEL evaluation is expensive, so be sure you really need it.